WebSocket Server doesn't receive messages
I'm trying to create and use a websocket server on C#. This is the code for the ws:
class WebSocketServer
{
    private static async Task HandleWebSocketAsync(HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client connected");

        var wsContext = await context.AcceptWebSocketAsync(null);
        WebSocket webSocket = wsContext.WebSocket;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        try
        {
            while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

                if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
                {
                    string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count);
                    Console.WriteLine("Received message: " + message);

                    // Invia un messaggio di risposta al client
                    string responseMessage = "Echo: " + message;
                    byte[] responseBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseMessage);
                    await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(responseBuffer), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (webSocket != null)
            {
                webSocket.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    public static async Task StartServerAsync(string url)
    {
        HttpListener httpListener = new HttpListener();
        httpListener.Prefixes.Add(url);
        httpListener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine($"WebSocket server listening on {url}");

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpListenerContext context = await httpListener.GetContextAsync();

                if (context.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
                {
                    _ = HandleWebSocketAsync(context); // Non-blocking call
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 400; // Bad Request
                    context.Response.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "http://localhost:2080/";
        await StartServerAsync(url);
    }
}

and it works because in the console I read the message: "WebSocket server listening on http://localhost:2080/"
The code for test is this:
class WebSocketClient
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Indirizzo del server WebSocket
        string serverUri = "ws://localhost:2080/"; // Cambia l'URL se necessario
        using (ClientWebSocket clientWebSocket = new ClientWebSocket())
        {
            try
            {
                // Connessione al server WebSocket
                await clientWebSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(serverUri), CancellationToken.None);
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to WebSocket");

                // Invia un messaggio di prova
                string message = "Hello, Server!";
                byte[] messageBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                await clientWebSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(messageBuffer), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
                Console.WriteLine($"Sent message: {message}");

                // Ricezione della risposta dal server
                byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[1024];
                WebSocketReceiveResult result = await clientWebSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(receiveBuffer), CancellationToken.None);
                string responseMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receiveBuffer, 0, result.Count);
                Console.WriteLine($"Received message from server: {responseMessage}");

                // Chiudere la connessione
                await clientWebSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Closing", CancellationToken.None);
                Console.WriteLine("WebSocket closed");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}

but when I run this code the console shows me:
"Error: The server returned status code '503' when status code '101' was expected.
C:\Users\francesco.mv\OneDrive - Digitronica\Desktop\Scanner_Fra\Solutions\TestSender\bin\Debug\net6.0\TestSender.exe (process 16304) exited with code 0."
I expect that the message would be received by the WebSocket server. I tried also to write similar codes in javascript with same host and port and those worked but when I try to reply the same on C# it doesn't work.
